# how can I view the history of a file with visual studio online? (Monaco)

Tags: git, azure-devops

I accidentally committed some code while trying visual studio online "Monaco" and now want to view the history of the file to get the old version. when I right click on the file there is no option for "view history"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can see your committed changes in a specific revision with git history; but this feature is available if you have a ".git" folder at the root of your project.

There is an easier way to view all the modifications of a specific revision. To do this, you have to type the following command to view all the commits of your project from its creation.

> git log

This command can be helpful when you want to do something on a specific revision (and, yes, to view the history of your project, obviously). In your case, you can see all the committed changes of a specific revision with the following command :

> git diff [REVISION]

Example :

> git diff aff840

Where **aff840** is the hash of the specified commit. (You are not obliged to indicate all the hash of your commit. In my case, i use the id **aff840** in order to avoid the real hash, which is **aff840c678eed2f1d8aebe71399ba388e9c300d5**.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you can't see it in your system as both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Online support this option.

In Visual Studio:

[image]

In Visual Studio Online:

[image]

Comment: I should have specified, I am trying to view the history of a file in visual studio online "Monaco" because the only folder i see in the non-Monaco version is the "BuildProcessTemplates" folder